# Circular structure in "getInitialProps" result of page "/[slug]"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having getting this error, already read in the documentation and other answers, but still do not understand why.

What I am trying to do is an api call, if there is a matching post, I want to render the Post component, if not, I want to redirect or render the error page.

When I click on an existing post link, I get the post, but when I put something random to generate a 404 status, I get the title error.

Here is my Post page:

```
const PostPage = ({ post }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {post.status === 200 ? (
                <Post post={post.data.items[0]} />
            ) : (
                <Error statusCode={post.status} />
            )}
        </>
    );
};

PostPage.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
    const post = await getPostBySlug(query.slug);
    return { post };
};
```

and my _error.js page:

```
function Error({ statusCode }) {
    return (
        <p>
            {statusCode
                ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
                : "An error occurred on client"}
        </p>
    );
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
    const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
    return { statusCode };
};
```

complete code:
 https://gitlab.com/flakesrc/blog-webstation-next

Comment: i am having the same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning {post}, return post.data. It will solve the issue.